# Access to disposed closure in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

*I'm investigating Microsoft enterprise library  (data application block)  -- The  samples sln.*

They have a sample of reading data asynchronously ( `IAsync` , although the new ver (6) also support `async`).

But Resharper(*or visual studio- nevermind*) shows me  : "Access to disposed closure" : (first i will show the image , so it will be clearer  , then i'll paste the code )

[image]

code :

```
/*1*/    [Description("Execute a command that retrieves data asynchronously")]
/*2*/    static void ReadDataAsynchronously()
/*3*/    {
/*4*/        if (!SupportsAsync(asyncDB)) return;
/*5*/   
/*6*/        using(var doneWaitingEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
/*7*/        using(var readCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
/*8*/        {
/*9*/            try
/*10*/            {
/*11*/                // Create command to execute stored procedure and add parameters
/*12*/                DbCommand cmd = asyncDB.GetStoredProcCommand("ListOrdersSlowly");
/*13*/                asyncDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "state", DbType.String, "Colorado");
/*14*/                asyncDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "status", DbType.String, "DRAFT");
/*15*/                // Execute the query asynchronously specifying the command and the
/*16*/                // expression to execute when the data access process completes.
/*17*/                asyncDB.BeginExecuteReader(cmd,
/*18*/                    asyncResult = >
/*19*/                    {
/*20*/                        // Lambda expression executed when the data access completes.
/*21*/                        doneWaitingEvent.Set();
/*22*/                        try
/*23*/                        {
/*24*/                            using(IDataReader reader = asyncDB.EndExecuteReader(asyncResult))
/*25*/                            {
/*26*/                                Console.WriteLine();
/*27*/                                Console.WriteLine();
/*28*/                                DisplayRowValues(reader);
/*29*/                            }
/*30*/                        }
/*31*/                        catch (Exception ex)
/*32*/                        {
/*33*/                            Console.WriteLine("Error after data access completed: {0}", ex.Message);
/*34*/                        }
/*35*/                        finally
/*36*/                        {
/*37*/                            readCompleteEvent.Set();
/*38*/                        }
/*39*/                    }, null);
/*40*/   
/*41*/                // Display waiting messages to indicate executing asynchronouly
/*42*/                while (!doneWaitingEvent.WaitOne(1000))
/*43*/                {
/*44*/                    Console.Write("Waiting... ");
/*45*/                }
/*46*/   
/*47*/                // Allow async thread to write results before displaying "continue" prompt
/*48*/                readCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
/*49*/            }
/*50*/            catch (Exception ex)
/*51*/            {
/*52*/                Console.WriteLine("Error while starting data access: {0}", ex.Message);
/*53*/            }
/*54*/        }
/*55*/    }
```

Question :

Why is it giving this warning ? there is a `manualreset-checked-signal` (which runs in a loop) which **prevents** the `using` clause to be reached - which means  - no `dispose` will call .

So why does it yell (warning) ?

Comment: Aside: Why are you using async calls when you're waiting for the result? Seems like using `Task`s would be more straightforward here.

Comment: **SAMPLES** SLN. this SLN contains 15 more examples which also uses TASK( async). that's not my question though.

Comment: I'm curious - are there simpler variants of this situation that R# is smart enough to recognize as "safe"? I would be surprised if so.

Comment: My guess is simply that R# isn't perfect. It can't know (i.e. its static analysis isn't advanced enough to know about how the event interacts with an async call) that the lambda is never called after the `using` goes out of scope, so it warns you this might happen.

Comment: @millimoose well you said that. me -- I thought this is something I should learn from :-)

Comment: I don't understand your statement *"there is a manualreset (which runs in a loop) which prevents the using clause to be reached."*  Even if that were true, R# isn't smart enough to know that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant Waitone which yield a result which is checked under a while loop.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The sample might well be correct. It probably is. R# is trying to prevent you `event.Set()` being called after the `using` block finishes. With async calls or **any** use of that object in a lambda, this is theorethically possible. The warning doesn't mean "this is a bug", but "this might be a bug and you should take a look at this code more closely"

Comment: @default.kramer: a simple repro, which I believe is guaranteed to never actually trigger the issue warned about:  using (var foo = new Foo()) { await Task.Run(()=>foo.Method()) }

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You pass `doneWaitingEvent` to a lambda that may extend beyond the scope of the using block. I.e. there's a risk that `Dispose` will have been called when the lambda executes.

Answer (score 59):

It yells warning because the engine is not smart enough to figure out that the using block will never be exited before the delegate code completes. That is why this is a warning not a error.

You can safely ignore this warning, you can have resharper suppress the warning by wrapping the lines with special comments

```
asyncDB.BeginExecuteReader(cmd, asyncResult =>
{
    // Lambda expression executed when the data access completes.
    // ReSharper disable AccessToDisposedClosure
    doneWaitingEvent.Set();
    // ReSharper restore AccessToDisposedClosure
    try
    {
        using (IDataReader reader = asyncDB.EndExecuteReader(asyncResult))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            DisplayRowValues(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error after data access completed: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // ReSharper disable AccessToDisposedClosure
        readCompleteEvent.Set();
        // ReSharper restore AccessToDisposedClosure
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: Or if you control the function being called you can use JetBrains' `[InstantHandle]` annotation to mark it safe for all the different invocations. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159776/access-to-disposed-closure-mark-methods-as-safe)

Comment: @jtb That is new to resharper in one of the more recent releases I believe. Feel free to post an answer with the annotation. I would upvote it

Comment: You may also use "ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure" to avoid the second comment

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see ReSharper's warnings is that ReSharper's code flow analysis engine is not strong enough to see what is going on: they assume that your code could get to the end of the `using` clause without `doneWaitingEvent` being set, which is not possible due to a `while` loop:

```
while (!doneWaitingEvent.WaitOne(1000)) {
    Console.Write("Waiting... ");
}
```

The loop will keep printing the `"Waiting... "` line until `doneWaitingEvent.Set();` gets called, preventing your code from reaching the end of the `using` block. Same goes for the other warning.

Long story short, this warning can be safely ignored. Add ReSharper's "ignore this warning" comments, and optionally file a bug report with them.

Comment: To future readers, on the "Optionally file a bug report with them", don't dismiss this idea thinking "Oh they are a big company and won't listen to me". I had a similar "not necessary warning" suggesting I should use a different overload of `CreateLinkedCancelationTokenSource`, I reported it and [they fixed it right away](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-425219).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'd say it depends... I've created two very serious bugs a _long_ time ago and they still have not fixed them. [First](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-416709#tab=History), and [second](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-349986).

Comment: Looks like they fixed the second, and the first is assigned (to the same person who fixed the second). They aren't just ignoring them :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain. I too filled a bug and Resharper team fixed it in less than 2 weeks.