# Access to disposed closure - mark methods as safe

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, resharper, idisposable

This is about ReSharper's warning "Access to disposed closure" which usually appears when an object which is later disposed is used in a lambda. [Access to disposed closure in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620430/access-to-disposed-closure-in-c) discusses this in a bit more detail.

My question is: For methods that take such lamdbas and execute them immediately (so you can be sure they are always executed before the said object is disposed):

Is there a way to mark them as safe, so that any code using that method does no longer produced those warnings?

Example:

```
using (var myObject = new MyDisposableObject())
{
    DoThisTwice(() => myObject.DoSomething());
}

...

void DoThisTwice(Action do)
{
    do();
    do();
}
```

DoThisTwice takes a delegate (or a lambda) and executes it synchronously. By the time the method returns, the lambda will no longer be executed. Only then the `myObject` is disposed, so we are good to go. We could mark the line calling `DoThisTwice` with a comment, but that has to be done in all places using the method in a similar way. Instead I would like to mark `DoThisTwice` as safe so Resharper does not display any warnings for any callers of the method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use ReSharper's annotations to fix this. ReSharper has no way of knowing how long the closure will last, e.g. it might be assigned to a field, and so it warns you that you might possibly be using something that will be disposed by the time the lambda is called.

You can fix it like this:

```
void DoThisTwice([InstantHandle] Action action)
{
    action();
    action();
}
```

The `InstantHandle` attribute tells ReSharper that the action is called immediately and not stored beyond the scope of the method.